# How to extract a part of file name in unix/linux shell script

Tags: shell, string

My file name is  `Oracle.2347263_testing_152607.csv`
I tried this :

```
echo Oracle.2347263_testing_152607.csv | sed -e 's/.*G.//'   \-e 's/.csv//'
```

but I didn't get the result I expected.

I want to extract `2347263` from `Oracle.2347263_testing_152607.csv`
please help

Comment: `awk -F'[._]' '{print $2}'`

Comment: `grep -o "\b[0-9]\+"`

Comment: If you're using bash and the filename is already in a variable, this is cheaper: `i=Oracle.2347263_testing_152607.csv` and then `j=${i#Oracle.*} ; echo ${j%%_*}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo Oracle.2347263_testing_152607.csv | sed -e 's/Oracle.\([[:digit:]]*\)_.*/\1/'
2347263
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this but got some error  sed: illegal option -- r
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]

Comment: "got some error"  What error?  It works fine for me.  If it doesn't work for you, show me exactly what happened.

Comment: sed: illegal option -- r
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]

Comment: @ora_unix OK.  That error looks like you are using a BSD `sed`.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$ echo Oracle.2347263_testing_152607.csv |cut -f 2 -d "." |cut -f 1 -d "_"
2347263
```